# What are the options for the `artifact` argument in the magick::image_get_artifact() function?

Tags: r

In the `magick::image_get_artifact()` function documentation, it says

> **artifact**:  string with name of the artifact to extract, see the image_deskew for an example.

I can't figure out what the possible options are for the `artifact` argument.  For what it's worth, I'm trying to extract the colors from the image.

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.12.3
#> Enabled features: cairo, freetype, fftw, ghostscript, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fontconfig, x11

img <- image_read('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
image_get_artifact(img, 'colorspace')
#> [1] ""
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What does `str(img)` return?

Comment: @IRTFM Not much.  It returns "Class 'magick-image' <externalptr>"

Comment: Are you sure that the colorspace attribute is stored in the list of artifacts?

Comment: @IRTFM I'm not sure what's stored in there.  I just used colorspace as an example.

Comment: My understanding from reading the sketchy documentation, which had no worked examples of using the function you chose,  regarding the nature of artifacts is that they are additions or modifications to an original image. So if I'm correct then there might be no artifacts in a particular image.

Comment: @IRTFM, thank you for digging into it.  I'm not able to find anything in the documentation either.

Comment: I haven't been able to construct a working example but this section of the docs suggests that artifacts are constructed with "defines" (see...https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#define ) and the R magick package does allow some sort of such operation with `image_set_defines`.